# Help me identify an SMD diode

Tags: pcb, diodes, identification, surface-mount, camera

I have a faulty power supply circuit of a PELCO PTZ camera. It has a burnt diode with the marking CT 6DZRS. I can't find the exact specs or type of the diode. The image is attached

Help will be much appreciated.

[image: Diode]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [Littelfuse SMBJ43CA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Littelfuse-SMBJ43CA_C224021.pdf) bi-directional TVS diode.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Electrostatic-and-Surge-Protection-TVS-ESD_Littelfuse-SMBJ43CA_C224021.html))